# postgres не дает создать индекс

Tags: postgresql

База перенесена из mssql в postgres. Создаю полнотекстовый индекс на поле с xml данными.

```
ALTER TABLE "Docs" ADD "tsv" tsvector; 
update "Docs" set "tsv" = to_tsvector('russian',"xml");
```

Но получаю предупреждения и ошибку:

```
Notice: words longer than 2047 chars are ignored
Error: string is too long for tsvector (3m bites, max 1m bites)
```

Как я понял, там встречаются длинные слова и размер некоторых документов слишком большой для индекса, вопрос, что делать? можно как то увеличить лимит?

Comment: Это ограничение, значение tsvector не может быть более 1Мб https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/textsearch-limitations

Comment: ок понял, а что можно придумать? можно как то указать ему что если длинее - обрезай

Comment: посмотрите тут https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/PostgreSQLFullText есть описание как обрезать строку